# Using Blaze on meteor is not working the way tutorials say it will

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, meteor-helper, blaze-html

My sidebar needs to load the names and paths out of the the nodes collection.
my publication.js

```
Meteor.publish('nodes', function(){
return Nodes.find();
```

});
my nodes_find.js in the server file with the publication.js file

```
if(Nodes.find().count() === 0){
Nodes.insert({
    name: "Example Node",
    path: "ExampleNode"
});
Nodes.insert({
    name: "Node 2",
    path: "ExampleNode"
});
Nodes.insert({
    name: "Node 3",
    path: "ExampleNode"
});
```

}
the Html block for the nodes and paths to show up on

```
<template name="sidebar">
<ul class="sidebar-nav" id="sidebar" role="navigation">     
 <div class="nodes">
  {{#each nodes}}
  <li>
    <a href="{{path}}">
      {{name}}
    </a>
  </li>
  {{/each}}
  </div>
</ul>
```

and finally the sidebar.js file

```
Template.sidebar.helpers({
nodes: function(){
    return Nodes.find();
}
```

});

although all I get is 4 paper thin tabs with no names and no paths. 
I have gone over the Discover Meteor book and done the practice and
have seen how they use it and looked on many forumns and have seen this
exact code work. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Have you subscribed to the publication? (Or have autopublish on?)

Comment: @bluebird Yes i have published and subscribed.                            Server side Meteor.publish('nodes', function(){
    return Nodes.find();
});                                                                                                                 client side    Meteor.subscribe('nodes');

Answer (score 1):

@Faysal Ahmed thank you for suggesting the console tests. I had completely overlooked that idea. I had not though that the database would have kept the old database from way back when I first made the app. 
So I researched it and found that using Meteor reset would help with clearing the database.
Now I have what I want on my site thank you very much for the idea.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have forgotten to subscribe your publication. Or if your `autopublish` is installed then you don't need to subscribe. And please check your client console if your data is really getting passed in the client or not.

Comment: I have subscribed in the client and published in the server and have removed the autopublish. But how would I go about checking my client console for the passed data.

Comment: I went in and typed Nodes.find().fetch() and was returned 4 objects when there should only be 3 and the titel: not name: was Node 1 for all of them.